# How to insert information from database into my php/display on my website?

Tags: php, mysql, database

All my information is going into the database that is being saved but I want it to come back up when I log in using a unique email. I have tried a lot of different codes within php. This is what I recently tried.

```
$result_habit = mysqli_query ($con, $query_habit); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_habit) ==1) {
        echo "found the row for ", $Email;
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_habit);
        echo "$row[c1]"
```

I want it to display the information from the table 'habit' and each row is labeled c1, c2, c3, etc 
Is there anything else I have to do to get the saved data to display for each unique login email?
thanks

Comment: you code above have an error if (mysqli_num_rows($result_habit) ==1) {  is without close "}".. echo "$row[c1]" missing semicolon ";"

Comment: `echo "$row['c1']";` shouldn't have quotes around $row (so make it `echo $row['c1'];`), plus the things that @parkway stated. `echo "{$row['cid']}";` would work, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_habit = mysqli_query ($con, $query_habit); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_habit) == 1) {
    echo "found the row for ", $Email;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_habit);
    echo $row['c1'];
}
```

This should be the correct way to write the code. All you seemed to have missed was a closing bracket and echoing the row variable correctly.